# different session for modules in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have created two modules:

1. Customer Module
2. Brand Module

Now when I login into customer module I want that I should not be logged in into Brand module.

Is there a way for me to differentiate between these two modules in session?

Comment: why cant you use role based permission instead of trying with different session?

Comment: Coud this help? http://webtips.krajee.com/different-backend-frontend-sessions-yii-advanced-app/

Comment: @lalithkumar I have tried that. It does not work well with my app

Comment: @robsch It can help if i can create different main.php for both the modules